# What is the jar file for package com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.*?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, bea

When making remote call to the EJB from application on WebLogic 12c web server it thorws

```
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
```

When searching from google i could find this exception class only from springframework-beans but not from WebLogic/BEA specific jar files, that is could not find that jar file at all. Looks like springframework is like repacjaged by Oracle/BEA and put in a separate package.

What is the name of the containing jar file and where can i find it?

The exception itself is as follows:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Problem finding error class; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it here: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.spring_1.2.0.0_2-5-3.jar.  Version numbers may be different.